# Error in decode json code

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

i need help with decode json

```html
if($loop->have_posts()) :
    $json = '{';
    $json .= '
    "api_status":1,
    "api_message":"success",
    "data": [';
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $json .= '{
        "id":'.get_the_ID().',
        "post_name":"'.get_the_title().'"
        },
        ';
    endwhile;

    $json = substr($json,0,-1);
    $json .= ']}';

    echo $json;
endif;
break;
}
```

my error is

[image]

in the last `}` i have still `,` so i need to remove it.

but i dont know how ?
someone help me ?

Comment: why don't you use the built-in function `json_encode()`?

Comment: how ? have u give me a sample, thanks ^^

Comment: `echo json_encode($whateveryouwanttoencode);`

Comment: You could also check the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php _(tip: php.net is a very good resource...)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `rtrim($json, ",");` to remove last comma from json output

```
if($loop->have_posts()) :
    $json = '{';
    $json .= '
    "api_status":1,
    "api_message":"success",
    "data": [';
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $json .= '{
        "id":'.get_the_ID().',
        "post_name":"'.get_the_title().'"
        },';
    endwhile;


    $json = rtrim($json, ",");
    $json .= ']}';

    echo $json;
endif;
break;
}
```

another way

```
$json = new array();
if($loop->have_posts()) :
    $json["api_status"] = 1,
    $json["api_message"] = "success",
    $json["data"] = new array();
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $json["data"]["id"] = get_the_ID();
        $json["data"]["post_name"] = get_the_title();
    endwhile;
    echo json_encode($json);
endif;
break;
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend this method, since constructing JSON string from base is a bad idea. There are a lot of opportunities for things to go wrong.

Comment: that's true i recommend building `new array()` then using `json_encode`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `json_encode` is the way to go.

```
$toEncode = array(
    "api_status" => 1,
    "api_message" => "success",
    "data" => array()
);

while ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post();
    array_push($toEncode["data"], array(
        "id" => get_the_ID(),
        "post_name" => get_the_title()
    ));
}

echo json_encode($toEncode);
```

However, I do not quite understand how your system for posts work. Are you using some type of iterator?

Answer (score 1):

You can use php function json_decode / encode:

- [JSON_DECODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
- [JSON_ENCODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

f.ex.

```
json_decode($variable, true);
json_encode($variable, true);
```